# XML XSLT Delete space in node

Tags: xml, xslt

i'm working on a school project in xml/xslt . I'm doing a transformation of a xml file.

In my xml file there is a tag  and it appears in différent way:

This one :

```
<item year="2016" scriptwriter="duval" artist="rouge">Calvin Wax</item>
```

And this one:

```
  <item year="2013" scriptwriter="ranouil" artist="jailloux billon">
    La dernière conquête
  </item>
```

I want this result in my text : Calvin Wax published in 2016, S, A,

but i have this one with the second way:

La dernière conquète 
published in 2013, S, A,

Any ideas to deal with that ?
Here is my xslt code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" id="p2"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="eol" select="'&#10;'" as="xsd:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="alinea" select="'&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;'" as="xsd:string"/>

    <xsl:template match="comics">
        <xsl:apply-templates select ="collections"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="collections">
       <xsl:apply-templates select ="series"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="series">
        <xsl:value-of select="$eol"/>
        <xsl:text>     serie: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$eol"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$eol"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>

   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(item)"/>
        <xsl:text>     </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text> published in </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@year"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="@additional='true'">
            <xsl:text>H, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="./@scriptwriter">
                 <xsl:text>S, </xsl:text>
             </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./@artist">
                <xsl:text>A, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="$eol"/>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first exprression

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(item)"/>
```

doesn't match the desired `text()` node, because the context item is already `<item>` due to the template's matching rule. So change it to

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
```

and (probably) remove the following `<xsl:apply-templates/>` (or change it to something more specific).
Then, the result should be

```
Calvin Wax      published in 2016, S, A, 
La dernière conquête      published in 2013, S, A,
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i replaced the line andd removed the apply template i change the place of my xsl text before and now it works prefectly !